# Is there a test if the result of this function is false? (Unity C unit test)

Tags: c, unit-testing

I wanted to do unit tests for the functions in my game.
In this case, I did the first test to see if the result is true but I don't seem to find a solution if the result is false

```
void test_pion_available(void)
{
    int a;
    a = pion_available();

    TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL_INT(1, a);

    /* miss the test if the result is false */

}
```

Comment: `a` is either true or false. So your test must test this. Just testing for true is incorrect.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie `a` can be any value between `INT_MIN (<= -32767)` and `INT_MAX (>= 32767)`, not only true or false. Only checking against `1` doesn't seem sufficient to check if the result is true.

Comment: @MikeCAT, OK, but the point is that the logic of the function is that a pion is either available or not, so the function is correct if `a` is either true or false, and this should be tested. `EQUAL_INT` is the wrong test.

Comment: @MikeCAT, further, the valid values of `a` depend on the definition of `pion_available`

Answer (score 1):

There may be some better way in you testing framework (like `TEST_ASSERT_FALSE(a);`?), but at least values other than 0 means true and 0 means false in C, so you can check if the result is 0 to check if the result is false.

```
void test_pion_not_available(void)
{
    int a;
    a = pion_available();

    TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL_INT(0, a);

}
```

Answer (score -1):

after some reseachers i found this:

```
void test_pion_not_available(void)
{
   int a;
   a = pion_available();

   TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL_INT(1, a); // or TEST_ASSERT(a == 1)

   // test if the result is false 

   TEST_ASSERT_FALSE(a != 1); //Evaluates whatever code is in condition and fails if it evaluates to true

}
```